# linux clipboard update appears to persist reboot

Tags: linux, debian, security, clipboard

I was horrified to reboot Debian Buster after a recent update to find that there is a log of previous copy-and-pastes, including passwords. Isn't that kind of thing supposed to live only in the RAM?

A quick search reveals there probably has been some kind of re-write :

https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/1134lcm/clipboard_just_got_an_update_that_makes_copying/

Does anyone know what they have done to it and how you can mitigate the security risk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Isn't that kind of thing supposed to live only in the RAM?

I honestly don't see why! Where the clipboard contents are stored is very much an implementation detail that hopefully no user has to care about :)

Think about it this way: if it was on the clipboard, any program with clipboard access could have gotten it, anyway. What these clipboard managers do, any program can do.

So, and here's where I can understand you seeing a shift in security, the only difference would be that someone with physical access to your machine (e.g. after having stolen your laptop) could read the comments from disk without you being logged in. Now, I will leave the assessment of how much you are personally at risk for that kind of targeted theft up to the James Bond reading this answer, but it is a security risk.

Depending on which desktop environment you're using on your debian, the way these contents are stored differs, because you might get different clipboard manager plugins for gnome shell, plasma,...

The clipboard program your Reddit post links to is just one of many clipboard programs, and I have never seen it. Debian doesn't even package it!

So, anyways, yes, chances are the passwords you copy and paste at some point hit the permanent storage. Fun fact: so does the cookie with with which your browser proves that you are you after you have successfully logged in, and these cookies are immediately useful and there's documented cases of journalists going into shady internet fora and buying malware-extracted bundles of such session cookies collected from hundreds of users.

But to mitigate the risks of your clipboard contents (and session cookies) being extracted by someone with physical access to your unpowered machine, you would choose to use storage encryption - typically, something like full disk encryption set up at installation time. (If I remember the debian installer correctly, there is an "encrypted LVM" selection at installation target device selection during in the debian installer). Then, someone stealing your unpowered machine will have won nothing, because they still would not know the storage decryption secret that's needed to make sense of your data.

Comment: But what is "fora"? ;-)

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov pluram form of "forum"

Comment: Woah, never knew about that. Google, "forums" About 565,000,000 results (0.56 seconds). "fora" About 395,000,000 results (0.48 seconds). This looks archaic :-)

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov "archaic" for something with 400 million results might be a bit harsh :D

Comment: Not gonna argue about that :-) You live and you learn. Thanks anyways :-)

Comment: Thanks, I do have full disk encryption set up at installation time. What if though, I copied and pasted the nuclear codes into my one-time-pad encrypted email then forgot about it and after a reboot when I was off-guard someone stole the PC. Could end badly.. Had not thought about the cookies either being a security risk but now that you mention it.. I mitigate that for chromium anyway with this command `rm -rf ~/.cache/chromium && rm -rf ~/.config/chromium` The clipboard seemed so ephemeral. So it is part of the Desktop not part of Linux itself, good to know.

Comment: yeah… now our threat model goes into the paranoid… I won't entertain that. If your unlocked PC gets stolen, you're hosed.

Answer (score 2):

This works at least for XFCE  under Fedora 37 (where `/var/tmp` is `tmpfs`), other DEs/clipboard apps/distros might need a different approach. This way XFCE clipboard history (`/var/tmp/xdgcache-birdie/xfce4/clipman`) doesn't survive a reboot/poweroff cycle.

```bash
$ cat /etc/profile.d/xdg_cache_in_var_tmp.sh
# could be more paranoid, and not accept any previously defined XDG_CACHE_HOME
if [ -z "${XDG_CACHE_HOME}" ] ; then
  XDG_CACHE_HOME="/var/tmp/xdgcache-${USER}"
  export XDG_CACHE_HOME
fi

if [ -d "${XDG_CACHE_HOME}" ]; then
  # verify existing dir is suitable
  if ! `test -G "${XDG_CACHE_HOME}" -a -w "${XDG_CACHE_HOME}"` ; then
    # else, make a new/secure one with mktemp
    XDG_CACHE_HOME="$(mktemp -d ${XDG_CACHE_HOME}-XXXXXX)"
    export XDG_CACHE_HOME
  fi
else
  mkdir -p "${XDG_CACHE_HOME}"
fi
```

Comment: ah excellent practical approach!

Comment: Thanks, that looks like an improvement, not sure if that puts it in ram but `/tmp/` doesn't survive the poweroff. Actually I think `/tmp/` is or is not on the disk or in the ram according to some settings file.